# Sliding Window Auto Increment Range

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I've created an initial dynamic range using an input value. For example, if my input is 10, the output is Average(A1:A10) in the cell B10.

How can I extend it so B11 will hold Average(A2:A11) and so on till the end of the range.

Ideally, using only the formulas without resorting to writing a script.

Here is the link to the google sheets: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c3IaAEfqjMlX1AlKqqBdUmETKltqXzsgv56K7y0Joo0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you can try:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   LET(val,A:A,
       sw,G1,
       {IF(SEQUENCE(sw-1),);
        MAP(
          SEQUENCE(COUNT(val)-sw+1),
          LAMBDA(i,AVERAGE(CHOOSEROWS(val,SEQUENCE(sw,1,i)))))}))
```

This formula is using `CHOOSEROWS` combined with `MAP` to iterate over each array of numbers of dimension `sliding_window` while taking the `AVERAGE`.